# Mysql insert - don't insert

Tags: php, select, insert

I'm new and have a question.

I think you know it , but I 'm new. 
So I hope you can see what here wrong is and why!

And this is my Code

```
<?php
    //Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
mysql_connect("****:3306", "****","*****!") or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich");
mysql_select_db("***") or die ("Datenbank existiert nicht");

$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID = " . intval($row['userID']));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
$row['userID'];
$row['userName'];
$select = mysql_query("INSERT INTO spielautomat_gewinn (userID, userName, gewinn) VALUES ('{$row['userID']}', ''{$row['userName']}', '+')");
}
?>
```

So, first select then insert.
But Insert don't work, but it may also be due to select, but insert don't work.
And so I can not check select.
And there are not Errors, the Website work but insert not.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting the `$row['userID']` in your select query?

Comment: Sry I'm new, but from select * from tbl_users?

Comment: you have two single quotes in front of ''{$row['userName']}' should be 1

Comment: It looks like {$row['userID']} should be outside of the double quotes and concatenated so it is the value of it and not that as a string

Comment: From the code shown, `$row` doesn't exist until you run the while loop, so it doesn't exist for your `SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID = `....

Comment: `''{$row['userName']}'` one quote too many here. Edit: It's already been said, my bad.

Comment: why don't you check for errors here? I don't see any error checking whatsoever.

Comment: `intval($row['userID'])` that will not come from your SELECT that you posted. Using `intval($row['userID'])` implies a previous SELECT query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i don't know what do you mean! There is a mistake, insert don't work! When I change the values to '1', '2', '3', then insert work

Comment: Consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php then apply that to your code / both queries. Then come back and tell us what errors you get; and you will get errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in

Comment: Your SELECT doesn't work. You need to fix that before focusing on your INSERT.

Comment: ^ which I said already.

Comment: Oh thanks, I try it now

Comment: So have I, I just keep rewording myself.. and now I'm done. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Okay that you are new :) every one was new. Step the million strats with one. 
This is the problem:
*) You did not save the $row['userID'] and $row['userName'] to variables 
Solution:

```
<?php
    //Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "kevin","madarmadar22!") or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich");
mysql_select_db("mohammada_kevin") or die ("Datenbank existiert nicht");

$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID = " . intval($row['userID']));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
{
  $uid = $row['userID'];
  $userName = $row['userName'];
$select = mysql_query("INSERT INTO spielautomat_gewinn (userID, userName, gewinn) VALUES ('$uid', '$userName', '+')");
}
?>
```

Comment: @MarziaAbasszadah Then it must be another problem :) .. Did you got problem message ?

Comment: @MarziaAbasszadah Try with mysql_fetch_assoc : Change the $row VAR. to fetch_assoc:
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select))

Comment: Hm, I got Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in